# Unable to get a Wi-Fi connection on a MacBook Pro running Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, macbook-pro

I have a 2017 MacBook Pro (15") and have put Ubuntu 18.04 on it. I've managed to get the drivers for keyboard and the trackpad working, but so far, I am unable to connect to Wi-Fi.

But I am able to see Wi-Fi networks, and I can attempt to connect to the (type in password etc. - yes, the password is correct), but the network utility just spins for a minute, and then asks for the password again.

I am happy to provide whatever details you need!

Comment: Update: I am able to connect to my phone's tethering, when I turn off authentication completely (no wpa2...).

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the Wi-Fi module was trying to randomize its MAC address via  NetworkManager.

The standard fix for this did not work, but I was able to get it to work by going into `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` and editing my specific connection.

I added `mac-address-randomization=0`, tried connecting to the network again, and everything worked!

Comment: No, this is apparently automatic with NetworkManager. Originally it was meant as a security feature by the devs.